# Split the API URL to Base, relative and Query

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

Issue with PowerBi service failed

Dataset includes a dynamic data source. Since dynamic data sources aren't refreshed in the Power BI service, this dataset won't be refreshed. Learn more: https://aka.ms/dynamic-data-sources.

How to divide this url to basic , relative and query

"https://api.com/data/v1/shift & "?page=" &
Number.ToText(i) & "&limit=10000"

"

My solution :

Base Url : https://api.com/data/v1/
Relative Path : shift

Comment: Looks like there is one quote missing in your URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PowerQuery replace this expression:

```
Web.Contents("https://api.com/data/v1/shift" & "?page=" & Number.ToText(i) & "&limit=10000")
```

with that one:

```
Web.Contents(
    "https://api.com/data/v1",
    [
        RelativePath = "shift",
        Query =
        [
            page = Number.ToText(i),
            limit = "10000"
        ]
    ]
```

Comment: What's wrong with my answer? Didn't it solve your problem?